# C - Convex Polygon - Sort Point (Clockwise)

Tags: c, sorting, polygon, convex

I have a **convex polygon** expressed by points. Points are expressed by **array of x-coordinates** and **array of y-coordinates**.

For example:

```
X = {6, 1, 5, 0, 3}
Y = {4, 0, 0, 4, 6}
```

How can I **sort** this points by **clockwise**? Number of points is not always the same, but polygon is still convex.

---

Is there a solution **without using** atan2 or other function from **math.h**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get away by [converting them to polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates). C has `atan2` so you could get away with:

```
atan2(y[0], x[0]);
```

After you obtain the respective angles you can use them to sort the points.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you to sort them by polar angle, but it's better to have a point inside of convex polygon as an origin to do that. to get such a point, you can just use a middle point of any diagonal of your poligon, for example ( (x[0] + x[2])/2, (y[0]+y[2])/2 ).